# Is there a theory of M-Estimation for non-unique argmins?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, optimization, references, estimators

Given some i.i.d. random variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in\mathbb R^d$, an [M-estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator) $\hat\theta_n\in\mathbb R^p$ is a parameter which minimizes
$$\hat\theta_n=\arg\min_{\theta\in\Theta} \sum_{i=1}^n\rho_n(x_i,\theta)\tag1$$
Where $\Theta\subseteq\mathbb R^p $ is the parameter space and $\rho_n:\mathbb R^d\times\Theta\to\mathbb R^+$ is an objective function.

In case where $\sum_{i=1}^n\rho_n(x_i,\theta)\to \varrho(\theta) $ in probability and/or expectation as $n\to\infty$ (i.e. if $\rho_n(\cdot,\cdot) =\rho(\cdot,\cdot)/n$ for some fixed function $\rho$), and $\varrho$ has a unique argmin $\theta_0$, there is quite a lot that can be said : up to additional technical conditions, one can show that $\hat\theta_n$ also converges in probability to $\theta_0$ and we also have that $\sqrt n\|\hat\theta_n-\theta_0\| $ is asymptotically normally distributed (this can be found in [Van der Vaart's Asymptotic Statistics (1996)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/asymptotic-statistics/A3C7DAD3F7E66A1FA60E9C8FE132EE1D)).

My question is : what can be said in the setting where $\varrho$'s argmin is not reduced to a point, but is rather a non-empty subset of $\Theta$ ? Can we say that the sequence $\hat\theta_n$ will converge to an element of $\arg\min\varrho $ ? Is the distance of $\hat\theta_n$ to $\arg\min \varrho$ asymptotically normal ?

This is a classical topic, so I guess these questions have been studied before (for instance, I know that M-estimators of a median are a thing), but I'm not very familiar with the subject and I can't find much online.

Direct answers as well as references would be appreciated, thank you.